# SAP Hybris - current selected category or product in storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, storefront, commerce

is possible get the currently selected product category or product in any mvc controller/service? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `ProductPageController`.`productDetail` & `CategoryPageController`.`category` . Is that what you need?

Comment: What does selected category or product mean? Do you mean the category/product that the current page shows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible.

In ProductPageController.java, you will find ProductData as below.

```
final ProductData productData = productFacade.getProductForCodeAndOptions(productCode, extraOptions);
```

You will get Categories from,

```
productData.getCategories()
```

and similarly you will get product as well.